# Using a nested for loop to count up and down

Tags: c++, loops

I was able to make a counter that goes up but what about down? Overall I want it to go like so:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

The code above you is the end result I want. But I cant seem to get the nested for loop to work for counting down.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int row, col;
    int size;
    int mych;

    int printch = 1;

    cout << "Size of Shapes (>0) ";
    cin >> size;

    while (size<0)
    {   
        cout << "\nSize of Shapes (>0) ";
        cin >> size;
    }

    cout << "Characters to use: ";
    cin >> mych;

    for(row = 1; row <= size; row++)
    {
        printch = mych;
        cout << "\n" << setw(8);

        for(col = 1; col <=row; col++)
        {
            cout << printch;
            printch++;
        }
    }

    for(row = size ; row <= size; row++)
    {
        printch = mych;
        cout << "\n" << setw(8);

        for(col = mych; col <=row; col++)
        {
            cout << printch;
            printch++;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\n";

    system ("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I'm stumped on this question. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Subtraction is a thing. It is inverse to addition. Just sayin'.

Comment: Try something simpler. Do you know how to print "54321"?

Comment: Negative. Im taking a C++ beginner class and my professor is very specific.

Comment: I am guessing @Beta meant that as an exercise. If you can solve that problem, then you can probably solve yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(row = size ; row <= size; row++)
```

(i.e. the second outer `for` loop)

should actually be:

```
for(row = size ; row >= 0; row--)
```

The thing is that as you start from size you should decrease row, instead of increasing it, and finish when you reach 0.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was always using the inner for loop! I did the col-- instead of row--. I also didnt set it to 0. :P

Again thank you very much! :D